# footable how do you remove search box

Tags: footable

In [FooTable](https://fooplugins.github.io/FooTable/docs/getting-started.html) how do you remove the `search box`?
 See search box picture [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KreFv.jpg).

Comment: which version of FooTable?

Comment: @barrypicker I am using the CDN - so I guess whatever latest version they push out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using FooTable v3.1.5.  When I want the search box to appear I add the following markup...

```html
<table id="mytable" class="table table-striped table-bordered footable" data-filtering="true">
```

if I wish to hide the search box i remove the attribute 'data-filtering'.

Example:

```html
<table id="mytable" class="table table-striped table-bordered footable">
```

I then use JavaScript to initialize the table...

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#mytable").footable();
});
```

Comment: Another possibility is to set data-filtering="false" in order to keep the attribute.

Answer (score 1):

if this would be your table container:

```html
<div class="container" >
    <table class="table table-striped" id="mytable">
    </table>
</div><!-- /container -->
```

Then just do a jquery hide for the table header row containing the search box:

```js
$("#mytable > thead > tr.footable-filtering").addClass("hidden");//hides the standard search footable search box
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function(){
$('.footable-filtering-search').html('');
});
```

Comment: Thank you @WEI - that is really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution: https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1lnzPpEZBmtYyhZyqELr7ZE1H2iR2vciuxg1d5yg7l-Y/edit?usp=sharing

If anyone has a better solution - I will gladly accept it as the answer.